# Можете подсказать почему не работают массивы в js?

Tags: javascript

```js
function NextSlide() {
  var kcliki = 0;
  var kolvoNone = [];

  kolvoNone[0] = dociment.getElementsByClassName("forCenter");
  kolvoNone[1] = dociment.getElementsByClassName("forYou");

  kcliki = kcliki + 1;
  kolvoNone[kclicki];
  alert('rabotaet)');
}
```

```html
<div id="slide-music">
  <img src="sucide.jpg" alt="" class="forYou">
  <img src="cry.jpg" alt="" class="forCenter">
</div>
```

Comment: __pashelTiUrod()__ no comment )))

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что массивы не работают?

Comment: может все таки `docUment` а не `docIment` ? Захватывая элемент по классу, надо или в цикле его прокручивать или индекс присваивать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function NextSlide() {
  var kcliki = 0;
  var kolvoNone = [];

  kolvoNone[0] = document.getElementsByClassName("forCenter")[0];
  kolvoNone[1] = document.getElementsByClassName("forYou")[0]; // нужен индекс [index]

  // document а не dociment

  kcliki = kcliki + 1;
  // kolvoNone[kclicki]; тут опечатка
  kolvoNone[kcliki];
  console.log(kolvoNone);
}

NextSlide()
```

```html
<div id="slide-music">
  <img src="sucide.jpg" alt="" class="forYou">
  <img src="cry.jpg" alt="" class="forCenter">
</div>
```

Comment: мда, чтобы не допускать такие ошибки, лучше использовать английский)

Comment: @Arthur, ты думаешь?  Привет...

Comment: Привет, да, лучше соблюдать эти правила, всё же синтаксис на английском, поэтому легче ориентироваться будет

Comment: Ну да, и то правда...